# adding inline image using Query String instead of public URL, Office365

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am adding inline image to Outlook body through compose message and came up with this issue. Here is the documentation for addFileAttachmentAysnc:

```
 Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync(attachmentURL, attachmentURL, options, callback);
```

My attachmentURL is a query string that has image ID, user token, smtp:

```
 http://namiq-pc/MailForms/api/GetAttachment?AttId=logo.png&MwToken=eteFIPebdPIKTLhfWKXDirp/rhdEVLmBxnKVU69mM36HgJCiINang8QDnB9w4ibKX6YG58esb1Kxa4oPw6s+QenADodv21An6/rjOkBIY1u5KObhrGhZFfOFRRD0+K7Q69J0VmL+6GY=&ReqId=HCYJ+G/WakTy/s1Hz5kURnU4cuANAb83lQ==&userSmtp=tw1621@mdev.org
```

Once I finish my compose form( a pop up window), I click finish which should add the image to the body. I should also mention that on my Controller, I am checking the IP of a user just to make sure they are allowed to make the request. When addFileAttachmentAsync finishes it sets img src to "cid:xxxx" and calls

```
Office.cast.item.toItemCompose(Office.context.mailbox.item).body.setSelectedDataAsync(body,{coercionType: "html", asyncContext: "set message body" }
```

When I click finish, text content is being added fine, I thin rendering image source forces it to go to my controller again and fails the IP check because now it is the Outlook making the request not the user(IP address of the request is in IPv6 format). (IP check has a list of potential users' IP addresses in 10.10.xx.xx format).

Now in my email body I get a broken image with my attachmentURL as a source and originalsrc is what I set

```
<div class="x_mw-images"><img src="http://namiq-pc/MailForms/api/GetAttachment?AttId=logo.png&amp;MwToken=eteFIPebdPIKTLhfWKXDirp/rhdEVLmBxnKVU69mM36HgJCiINang8QDnB9w4ibKOnFdBCeOpo1Nr8bCtXa4vyQ5PI/bOg8yTI/qpY5HVNpPVBQJghdmnAfgR/WTaGk0hAiQn3237yU=&amp;ReqId=IOyOCna5kLpAKN6EjFKuNExpYNANAb83lQ==&amp;userSmtp=tw1621@mdev.org" alt="logo.png" height="100" originalsrc="cid:1528819032946.png" size="90196" style="user-select: none;"></div>
```

The way I understand is whatever you put a source Outlook overrides it with the attachmentURL and sets your "src" value as a original source. Checking the IP address is a crucial step for my case, any idea how to get around this issue or may be explanation of what I am doing wrong would help.

Comment: Using IP address to validate a user has its challenges because network config can change. Have you looked at exchange identity token to determine user authorization?

Comment: I figured out a solution to this issue. The way my code worked is, it first sends a POST request with user token and path. This POST request returns back file names that need to grabbed from sevrer. Then I call addFileAttachmentAsync  with those filenames and some other details to help authentication. I do IP check when addFileAttachmentAsync makes the GET request to the server. This step succeeds because of the IP safe list. In the case when IP check fails, I am just making sure both POST and GET request are sent by the same address by comparing the hash of IPs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution to this issue. The way my code worked is, it first sends a POST request with user token and path. This POST request returns back file names that need to grabbed from sevrer. Then I call addFileAttachmentAsync  with those filenames and some other details to help authentication.

```
 http://namiq-pc/MailForms/api/GetAttachment?AttId=logo.png&MwToken=eteFIPebdPIKTLhfWKXDirp/rhdEVLmBxnKVU69mM36HgJCiINang8QDnB9w4ibKX6YG58esb1Kxa4oPw6s+QenADodv21An6/rjOkBIY1u5KObhrGhZFfOFRRD0+K7Q69J0VmL+6GY=&ReqId=HCYJ+G/WakTy/s1Hz5kURnU4cuANAb83lQ==&userSmtp=tw1621@mdev.org
```

I do IP check when addFileAttachmentAsync makes the GET request to the server. This step succeeds because of the IP safe list. In the case when IP check fails(which happens when compose form body is transformed to mail body), I am just making sure both POST and GET request are sent by the same address by comparing the hash of IPs.

Because the server makes the both requests in this last step, when everything goes right, they do match.You just need to carry POST request IP address throughout these steps(returning hashed IP from POST as a JSON) so you can compare it during GET.